# Android Eclipse Libgdx Tween velocity

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, tween

So I have a Tween that moves a Sprite from its current location to a touched location. The problem is that if the touched location is close to the Sprites current location, the speed is super slow. If the touched location is far away from the sprite, it moves very quickly.

My understanding is that the number at the end of the `Tween.to(mySprite, Type.POSITION_XY, 1.0f);`, statement is the time allotted for the tween to complete. Is there a way to base this on the distance of the touched location from the current location, or increase it steadily from the time of the touch till the Tween completes?

Basically what I am looking for is that the Tween moves the Sprite at a similar speed regardless of the distance.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to divide the distance traveled by your desired speed to get total time.  With easing, your speed won't be constant, but it will be the correct average speed.

```
static final float SPEED = 30; //in world units per second

...

Tween.to(mySprite, Type.POSITION_XY, Vector2.dst(mySprite.x, mySprite.y, destinationX, destinationY)/SPEED)
    .target(destinationX, destinationY);
```